# Where can I see the logs for failed airflow scheduler deployments?

Tags: git, airflow, kubernetes-helm, rancher, git-sync

I'm deploying Airflow with Helm (I'm using Rancher to do so)

I've set up `git-sync` to pull the DAGs from a private repo. Everything is working fine.

Now I want to switch to a different repo. I updated `repo` and `subPath`
in the Helm configuration

```yaml
    dags:
      gitSync:
        branch: master
        depth: 2
        enabled: true
        repo: ssh://git@gitlab.com:<repo path>.git
        sshKeySecret: airflow-ssh-git-secret
        subPath: jobs
```

My repo structure:

```
.
├── ...
├── jobs
    ├─ airflow
       ├─ dags.py
```

When I launch the deployment, the webserver starts up normally, and I can connect to it and view it's logs normally.

But the `scheduler` and `triggerer` fail. The only message I get in Rancher (on both components) is:

```
containers with incomplete status: [git-sync-init]
```

I don't know where to see the deployment logs (I can't connect to the pods), and I can't figure out what's wrong.